# Angular Routing adds %2F to Route instead of Backslash

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm creating a simple route to send a parameter to the URL.

HTML

```
[routerLink]="['/private/admin/System/',myParameter,'users/add-user']
```

Routing-Module

```
  { path: ':myParameter/users/add-user',  component: MyComponent},
```

Error

> Error: Cannot match any routes 'private/admin/System/PARAMETER/users**`%2F`**add-user

Angular creates Route with **%2F** instead of **/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass parameters separately, as array items

This should work:

```
[routerLink]="['/private/admin/System/',myParameter,'users','add-user']
//                                                       ^^^^^ Here, you need to split `user/add-user`
```

Comment: Yup !! It works !! Thank man !! I will accept your answer as soon as the time pass, it's saying to me that I have to wait to accept !! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it worked for you :) Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks, you too !!